# Ajuda com LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Quero saber como faço para criar um evento ao tocar em uma imagem usando a LibGdx...Estou tentando iniciar um jogo e adicionei uma imagem como botao de Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve implementar um **InputProcessor**, e defini-la como recebedora dos eventos :

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(instanciaInputProcessor);
```

Essa interface tem todos os tipos de eventos de input, no caso do touch, você vai precisar usar a câmera pra saber qual a posição relativa do toque(se vc usa só uma simples, com mesma dimensão da tela e sem escalar, não precisa), depois basta checar se essa posição está dentro dos limites da sprite. A wiki da libgdx mostra um exemplo completo :

```
public class SimplerTouchTest extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
public final static float SCALE = 32f;
public final static float INV_SCALE = 1.f/SCALE;
public final static float VP_WIDTH = 1280 * INV_SCALE;
public final static float VP_HEIGHT = 720 * INV_SCALE;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private ExtendViewport viewport;        
private ShapeRenderer shapes;

@Override public void create () {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(VP_WIDTH, VP_HEIGHT, camera);
    shapes = new ShapeRenderer();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override public void render () {
    //Provavelmente você está usando sprite-batch
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shapes.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapes.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapes.circle(tp.x, tp.y, 0.25f, 16);
    shapes.end();
}

@Override public void resize (int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}

@Override public void dispose () {
    shapes.dispose();
}
@Override public boolean touchDown (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    //Aki vocÊ verifica se o screenX e sceenY estão dentro dos limites da sprite.
    if(screenX > posicaoX && screenX < posicaoX+largura && screenY > posicaoY && screenY < posicaoY+altura){
        //evento aki
    }
    return true;
}
//Abaixo tem mais vários eventos que você tem a obrigação de implementar (ja q e interface, mas use apenas quando quiser)
@Override public boolean mouseMoved (int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return true;
}

@Override public boolean touchUp (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return true;
}

@Override public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override public boolean keyTyped (char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Tem como simplificar tudo, mas esse modo é o mais seguro que eu conheço